# 'Connection refused' error trying to follow the Python Elasticsearch example usage

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run the 'example usage' script for [Python Elasticsearch](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/):

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
print(res['created'])

res = es.get(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1)
print(res['_source'])

es.indices.refresh(index="test-index")

res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
print("Got %d Hits:" % res['hits']['total'])
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    print("%(timestamp)s %(author)s: %(text)s" % hit["_source"])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "elasticsearch_example_usage.py", line 10, in <module>
    res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 279, in index
    _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 327, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 105, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0be9c14890>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0be9c14890>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Can someone clarify why this doesn't work? Are there any additional commands I have to do to 'set up' Elasticsearch? The referenced website does not give any additional instruction or clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python Elasticsearch client is just one piece of the puzzle, it needs to work with an Elasticsearch server. When you call this:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
```

You're setting up a client connection to an Elasticsearch host. Calling it without arguments uses [default values](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/transports.html?highlight=urllib3httpconnection#elasticsearch.connection.Urllib3HttpConnection), attempting to hit port 9200 on localhost.

For setting up an Elasticsearch server, it's probably most useful to hit the [Elasticsearch site](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) and look at their documentation about running locally or in the cloud (whichever appeals to you). Following the [download](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) instructions will leave you with Elasticsearch running on localhost port 9200, which should get your example working.